# Downloading javascript generated content with PHP/CURL

Tags: javascript, php, curl, web, bots

So I'm writing a web-bot that analyses virtual prices on a web game (Using PHP & CURL). The problem i ran into is that price-lists is generated using javascript and I can't figure out how to download these and save into files. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a javscript interpreter to do it. You can try an emulator like [this one](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2006/01/19/j4p5-javascript-for-php5/) , but I think php isn`t best choice to do this.